# NSCoder - archive a pointer?

Tags: objective-c

I have an objective-c class which contains a pointer to another class. I want to archive an instance of this class via NSCoder:

```
@interface Barn
{
    int m_numHorses;

    // Barn does not allocate this instance, it just points to it.
    Farmer* m_pFarmer;
}
@end

...

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeInt:m_numHorses forKey:@"numHorses"];
    [encoder encode?:m_pFarmer forKey:@"pFarmer"];
}

- (void) setPointer:(Farmer*)pFarmer
{
    m_pFarmer = pFarmer;
}
```

How would I archive the m_pFarmer pointer? It doesn't make sense to me as all it is is an address, and I don't see what NSCoder could serialize to disk for you such that it knows how to restore the link later on when you deserialize?

Answer (score 7):

You can't directly encode a pointer, because when you unarchive the objects, the pointer's value is going to be entirely different.  I mean, you could store it with

```
encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(id) at:&m_pFarmer
```

but there's no guarantee that the deserialized pointer will point to the deserialized farmer; in fact, it's very very likely that it won't.

If `Barn` doesn't own the `Farmer`, then `Barn` shouldn't recreate it on deserialization; you'll end up with a new `Farmer` that's not separate from the original one.  What you need, then, is a way to find the deserialized instance of the original Farmer, and replace Barn's instance of the Farmer with the other one.

Somebody owns the `Farmer`, right?  So `Barn` needs to have a `findMyFarmer` method, which looks through all the `FarmerOwner`s and finds the original instance it should be using.  (Maybe by comparing a `farmerID` ivar on the `Farmer`?)  Once that's done, you can implement `-[NSObject awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)]` on the `Barn` to trigger a farmer-replacement routine.

Hope that makes sense.  Look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/) on Archiving and Serialization, especially the page on **Encoding and Decoding Objects** to see more about replacing objects on the fly.

**Update**

`NSArchiver`s and `NSKeyedArchiver`s  support the idea of [*conditional* archiving](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Concepts/archives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000946-142208), (via `encodeConditionalObject:`) in which the object is added to the archive only if some other object in the archive has already added it.  The documentation says "**Typically, conditional objects are used to encode weak, or non-retained, references to objects.**".  So if your `Farmer` is being archived already, then you'd want to add it, but if you're only encoding your `Barn` without any farmer, then you wouldn't want to.

Definitely check out the documentation referenced above.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning conditional archiving, could decode it normal after encode the weak reference with - (void)encodeConditionalObject:(id)objv forKey:(NSString *)key

Answer (score 3):

You should use `encodeObject:` and implement `NSCoding` in your `Farmer` class as well, so it gets called recursively.

Comment: Ah sorry I should have been more clear - m_pFarmer is simply a pointer to a Farmer object allocated elsewhere in the system - it is not owned by the Barn class instance -

Comment: Are you storing the Farmer object outside of this code? If you are not, it makes sense to me to save it recursively.

Answer (score 3):

You should first read the docs that BJ points to.

The serialization libraries are smart enough to detect repeats of the same object, and will only encode it one time. So in general, you should be encoding this object if you need it later. The serialization libraries can even handle graph loops. You do not need to worry about these things, and actively should *not* try to second-guess how other objects are going to handle this object. ObjC does not have the kind of strong object ownership concepts that C++ often requires. Reference counted memory management does not require it, and you shouldn't recreate it.

Speaking of reference counting, do you mean not to retain Farmer in your setter? Is this because Barn is already retaining Farmer? Or is this garbage collected code? Or was this an unintentional under-retain? This could definitely cause a crash when you deserialize this stuff if you've actually under-retained it.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want to encode the address held by the pointer (because you can guarantee the `Farmer` object will stay at that location until you decode the archive) then you can encode the pointer as an `NSInteger`.

i.e. `[encoder encodeInteger:(NSInteger)m_pFarmer forKey:@"pFarmer"];`

Generally speaking though, this is a bad idea unless you are very careful to hold onto the `Farmer` object longer than the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. In your case, I would generate a UUID (unique identifier) for the Farmer, using

```
var uniqueIdentifier: String = NSUUID().UUIDString
```

Then I would save this UUID on the Farmer using NSCoding.

I would also have the Barn point to the Farmer via this UUID (you can have a computed "Farmer" property on the Barn determining a Farmer via the UUID).
And save the UUID of the Barn with NSCoding.
This way, you will never lose the pointer when saving data on disk.

Of course, a better technical solution would be to use CoreData, but that's a different story ...

EDIT : I had a case in which I tried to encode a pointer to another object with NSCoding. My case was a stock alert pointing to a stock (defined as a property of the stock).
It appears that NSCoding created a copy of the original object, "frozen" in its current state. And that copy would live independently from the original object. Stocks have properties, some stored (current share price), other calculated (gain in currency or in %). The stored properties of the stock property of the stock alert were unchanged, while the computed properties (which depended on other factors) evolved.
So the conclusion of my experience would be that it's not a good idea trying to save a pointer to another object with NSCoding.